# How to get Wi-Fi and mobile network parameters in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking, parameters, windows-phone

My app requires the following parameters of mobile network:

- MCC (Mobile Country Code)
- MNC (Mobile Network Code)
- LAC (Location area code)
- CID (Cell identifier)
- cell's signal strength

And for Wi-Fi:

- MAC-adress
- signal strength

Also I need a device IP-adress for both variants.

Is there any API to get these parameters on Windows Phone 7? I can't find anything.

Comment: If this is possible then the answer is probably in this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708285(v=vs.92).aspx
I struggled to find a list of valid arguments for getting device properties. May I ask why you want all that network infomation? You can use things like the DeviceID if you want to uniquely identify a phone. http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/12/30/Getting-to-know-the-Identity-of-your-Windows-Phone-7-Application.aspx

Comment: Thanks for links. I want all that information because my app uses geolocation web-service which requires it. Generally speaking, I think that I can locate device through standart APIs, but web-service is more prefered.

Comment: I imagine you've already seen it but the standard way of doing it seems very well documented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to this information is not made provided. Presumably due to possible privacy/security related issues.

Additionally, if you created such an app it would not be acceptable to submit it to the marketplace as it would break [certifaction requirements](https://web.archive.org/web/20121118101127/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841(v=vs.92).aspx), specifically 2.7.1:

> Your application must determine location using the Microsoft Location Service API.