# How to get MCC and MNC in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

MCC，Mobile Country Code
MNC，Mobile Network Code
Is there a way to get MCC and MNC in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to get Wi-Fi and mobile network parameters in Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861789/how-to-get-wi-fi-and-mobile-network-parameters-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: What are you trying to do with those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't get MCC and MNC on Windows Phone 7 (and 8) devices.

Maybe with Windows Phone 9 ? :D

It's possible with Windows Mobile (with Radio Interface Layer) , but it's not implemanted on Windows Phone...

You can Get other Network Informations with the Network Information class.

Please Read [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for more informations.

Also, you can vote [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform) for improve features has you want in Windows Phone plateforme...  ANd [here it's RIL page](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2912629-implement-radio-interface-layer-)...

Comment: hope it is possible on windows phone 9 :)

Comment: thank u for the url you gave,time to post my advice and suggestion to MS now!

Answer (score 0):

With some Nokia Lumia phones you can enter "Field Test" menu by selecting ##3282# on dial pad. At least my Lumia 1020 with Lumia Cyan update shows that menu which gives very precise information about mobile network. You can also force the phone to use GSM/UMTS/LTE only and select different bands. I can see RCC Status, UARFCN, LAC, RAC, MCC-MNC, UTRAN Registration area, EC/Io, SINR, RSCP, ECNO and many more attributes throug this menu.